# How to use string variable like "day, month, year" in "1.VARIABLE.ago" time expression?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a parameter just like `params[:time_range]`.

In my controller, I want to use this time range parameter to specify a particular range at my query something like this:

```
# params[:time_range] = "week"
time = params[:time_range]
query = Article.where(created_at: 1.#{time}.ago)
```

Surely it doesn't work as it is right now.

Is there a way to convert `params[:time_range]` string into the type of month, day or week?

I tried to use `to_sym` but that `week` thing is not a symbol. When I try to find its class with `1.week` I get `Fixnum`.

Does anyone know a way to work this out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `send` to dynamically call a method in ruby.

```
1.send(time).ago
```

But be careful, with this your user can call any method on the object the way you did this, you should sanitize it before.

example :

```
time = 'day' unless ['day', 'month', 'year', 'week'].include? time
```

Comment: You're a saver :) Thank you!

Comment: You were so fast to answer but SOF does not let me to accept it before 10 more minutes :)